# How to modify EditText's content on-the-fly?

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` which requires certain on-the-fly formatting after each character when user types text into it. However, `TextWatcher` doesn't seem to be suitable for this since whenever the text is changed, it is called recursively:

> It is legitimate to make further changes to s from this callback, but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop, because any changes you make will cause this method to be called again recursively.

The formatter I've written keeps track of the whole string and applies characters one by one to it, formatting the text on the fly. The API of the formatter is something like this:

```
// This should be called with the newest character
// whenever the user gives input
public void append(char c) { ... }

// This should be called to get the correctly formatted string
// whenever it should be shown on the UI
public String getResult() { ... }
```

So, the question is: how would I hook my formatter into the `EditText`?

Comment: Have a look at how the [`PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java) class handles it.